# What does HTTP 2 mean for Web Developers

Tags: php, security, ssl, web-deployment

When it comes to building my web applications, I know HTTP 2 is going to be recommended for all traffic coming to the site. I understand the security concerns and the reason why it is recommended/forced to be used now.

When it comes the web-based languages I code in and understand such as Ruby, PHP, and Perl.

Is there any special functions that I will have to do to produce a secure connection to my server or all do we need to do is redirect all traffic to `https://` over `http://`?

Basically, my autoloading class in PHP would load all classes and functions for my web application to operate. Would I need to create a `SSL.class.php` for allowing the connection to be secure within my PHP?

Comment: You don't need an SSL class in your PHP now with http 1.1, because all that is handled by the webserver before it hits your PHP; http 2 will be the same as far as your PHP is concerned, no changes to code to handle ssl/tls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes in HTTP/2.0 over HTTP/1.1 are mostly relevant if your application streams large amounts of data to many simultaneous users.

> Is there any special functions that I will have to do to produce a secure connection to my server or all do we need to do is redirect all traffic to `https://` over `http://`?

No. HTTP/2.0 does not require TLS. If you want TLS (which, personally, ***I encourage***), you still need to send clients to `https://`.

> Basically, my autoloading class in PHP would load all classes and functions for my web application to operate. Would I need to create a SSL.class.php for allowing the connection to be secure within my PHP?

In most cases, the HTTP layer is a webserver problem, not a PHP-land application code problem.

If you are working on a framework that insists on parsing request headers and managing responses in a very HTTP-like fashion, then yes, you probably need to be aware of some of the changes in the new version of the protocol.

## Differences Between HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.0 for Developers

- [Servers can push more data over an established connection in HTTP/2.0](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PushResources). This is really neat if you need to push real-time notifications (e.g. what StackOverflow does).
- Better multiplexing and streaming; it's now possible to stream multiple resources over the same HTTP connection.

[Source](http://apiux.com/2013/07/23/http2-0-initial-draft-released)

Unless your application is keenly aware of networking protocols, it shouldn't matter much for our day-to-day CRUD interfaces.